# How to use the select AND

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been trying to use `AND` in my `SELECT`, but I got an error.

What is likely the correct way I should have written the code?

The code is:

```
$sel=mysql_query("SELECT  * from student, subject, studentmark
 where student.username='$name' AND studentmark.student_id='$name' AND studentmark.YEAR='$ya' AND studentmark.Term='FIRST' AND studentmark.Term='SECOND' AND studentmark.Term='THIRD' AND subject.code=studentmark.code AND student.username=studentmark.student_id");
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: studentmark.Term='FIRST' AND studentmark.Term='SECOND' AND studentmark.Term='THIRD' . This condition will never work & you'll get nothing in return. Also, you need to use JOIN instead of the following: student.username=studentmark.student_id

Comment: Perhaps those AND should be OR. (And within parenthesis.)

Comment: @jarlh Yeap. His query is a table joining query & as I think, he needs a query with at least 2 LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Also, please read this post about why you should not be using `mysql_query` - you really need to be using `mysqli_query` at the very least! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: Share your desired result from the dummy data

Answer (score 1):

A simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.  The result is something like this:

```
SELECT  *
from studentmark sm join
     student st 
     on sm.student_id = st.username join
     subject join
     on sm.code = su.code     
 where st.username='$name' AND sm.YEAR = '$ya' AND
       sm.Term in ('FIRST', 'SECOND', 'THIRD')
```

Also, learn to use table aliases.  They make queries easier to write and to read.

Answer (score 0):

You must use OR instead of AND
studentmark.Term='FIRST' AND studentmark.Term='SECOND'
The Value of Term can only has ONE Value

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what columns do you want to get from student, subject & studentmark tables & also relationship of those tables. So here is my idea:

1. Use OR instead of AND on the same column check: studentmark.Term='FIRST' AND studentmark.Term='SECOND' AND studentmark.Term='THIRD'. This will return nothing.
2. Use table join query instead of: subject.code=studentmark.code AND student.username=studentmark.student_id, it is not correct. Take a look here: [SQL Joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)